# Using ajax to load 2 different json file to combine into one object using Spread Operator

Tags: javascript, ajax, local-storage

I'm trying to load 2 different json files using the ajax method, with a callback function. In order 'pass' them to another function, I'm using localStorage(not sure if this is the best approach but it works)

Now when trying to combine the two I was hoping to use the spread operator, it doesn't exactly works the final result is omitting some of the values in the json files and showing the max length from the two with a few values combine.

```
//someitems
{ "items": [
  { "namezz": "Bike", "price": 100 },
  { "namezz": "TV", "price": 700 },
  { "namezz": "Album", "price": 10 },
  { "namezz": "Book", "price": 5 },
  { "namezz": "Phone", "price": 500 },
  { "namezz": "Computer", "price": 1000 },
  { "namezz": "Keyboard", "price": 25 }
]
}


//someMoreItems
{ "items": [
  { "namezz": "House", "price": 350000 },
  { "namezz": "Car", "price": 40000 },
  { "namezz": "Boat", "price": 16000 },
  { "namezz": "Moter bikes", "price": 20000 }
]
}

function loadDoc(location, callback) {
    var xyz = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xyz.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            this.responseText;

            callback.apply(xyz);
        }
    };

    xyz.open("GET", location, true);
    xyz.send();
}



function makeCombinationTwo() {
    var combine1;
    var combine2;

    var c1, c2;

    loadDoc("/_js/someitems.json", function () {
        // "this" is the XHR object here! ...in your nutcase example it is xyz ;-)
        combine1 = this.responseText;

        // localStorage to pass the varaible outside this functional scope :(
        localStorage.combine1 = combine1;
    });

    c1 = localStorage.getItem("combine1");
    combine1 = makeObj(c1).items;

    console.log(combine1);

    loadDoc("/_js/someMoreItems.json", function () {

        combine2 = this.responseText;

        localStorage.combine2 = combine2;
    });

    c2 = localStorage.getItem("combine2");
    combine2 = makeObj(c2).items;

    console.log(combine2);

    var newObj = { ...combine1, ...combine2 };
    console.log(newObj);

//    return newObj;

}





function makeObj(a) {
    return JSON.parse(a);
}



makeCombinationTwo();
```

the console.log shows only 7 items, the length of the larger object with combined of the other file:

```
0: {namezz: "House", price: 350000}
1: {namezz: "Car", price: 40000}
2: {namezz: "Boat", price: 16000}
3: {namezz: "Moter bikes", price: 20000}
4: {namezz: "Phone", price: 500}
5: {namezz: "Computer", price: 1000}
6: {namezz: "Keyboard", price: 25}
```

I expect to see 11 items. Thank you for any tips or ideas.

Comment: To merge objects that are inside an array it should have been: `newObj.items = [...combine1.items, ...combine2.items];`

Comment: I'm a noob, thank you~!
a question to the community, is using localStorage/session storage to pass the values around ok?  or is there a better approach?

Comment: I suggest opening a new question with proper context and what you want to achieve. That way u'll get much better reach/views of people who can help out.